# indexing Each documents field inside xml separately as separate document

Tags: xml, apache, indexing, solr

I am trying to index an xml having 1400 documents of data in following format(Each "information" field starts and ends is a separate entity of document.

```
<add>
<information>
    <id>a1a</id>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <bibliography>a. b. ,c</bibliography>
    <body>This sample one.</body>
    <title>Sample one</title>
</information>
<information>
    <id>a2a</id>
    <author>xyz</author>
    <bibliography>x. y.x</bibliography>
    <body>This is sample two</body>
    <title>Sample Two</title>
</information>
</add>
```

i used command prompt to commit the file using post command, java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=VR -Dtype=application/xml -jar post.jar VR.xml

Schema.xml (till field declarations)

```
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

   <field name="bibliography" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="body" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="sku" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="features" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="includes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />

   <field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />

   <field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>


   <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>


   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- catchall text field that indexes tokens both normally and in reverse for efficient
        leading wildcard queries. -->
   <field name="text_rev" type="text_general_rev" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- non-tokenized version of manufacturer to make it easier to sort or group
        results by manufacturer.  copied from "manu" via copyField -->
   <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

   <field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/>



   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>

   <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />

   <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />

 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

so, here i have added all the extra fields mentioned in the xml with the default configurations.

After indexing is completed and if i put Query here, The response given is

{
        "id": "VR",
        "content_type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content": [
          " \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n   \n     \n         a1a\n         abcd\n         a. b. ,c\n         This sample one.\n         Sample one\n    \n     \n         a2a\n         xyz\n         x. y.x\n         This is sample two\n         Sample Two\n    \n     \n  "
        ],
        "*version*": 1558754454898999300

Reponse expected is:

{
        "id": "abcd",
        "content_type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content": [
          " \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n   \n     \n         a1a\n         abcd\n         a. b. ,c\n         This sample one.\n         Sample one\n    \n     \n         a2a\n        "
        ],

```
    "_version_": 1558754454898999300
```

{
        "id": "xyz",
        "content_type": [
          "application/xml"
        ],
        "content": [
          " xyz\n         x. y.x\n         This is sample two\n         Sample Two\n    \n     \n    "
        ],
        "*version*": 1558754454898999301

Let me know, where i am missing and please suggest the congigurations required, if any extra information is required feel free to ask.

Comment: What is the response if you try this http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?q=*%3A*

Answer (score 0):

I think, everything is indexed as one document.

change `<information></information>` tags to `<doc></doc>`

```
<add>
<doc>
    <id>a1a</id>
    <author>abcd</author>
    <bibliography>a. b. ,c</bibliography>
    <body>This sample one.</body>
    <title>Sample one</title>
</doc>
<doc>
    <id>a2a</id>
    <author>xyz</author>
    <bibliography>x. y.x</bibliography>
    <body>This is sample two</body>
    <title>Sample Two</title>
</doc>
</add>
```

Comment: Sorry, still the same Response for Query. Any other solution if You have?

Answer (score 0):

Convert you xml to the below format :

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">a1a</field>
    <field name="author">abcd</field>
    <field name="bibliography">a. b. ,c</field>
    <field name="body">This sample one.</field>
  </doc>

  <doc>
    <field name="id">a2a</field>
    <field name="author">xyz</field>
    <field name="bibliography">x. y. ,z</field>
    <field name="body">Sample Two.</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Now you can post data using the below command :

```
/opt/solr/bin/post -c collection_name VR.xml
```

Comment: Sorry, still the same Response for Query. Any other solution if You have?

Answer (score 0):

The XML document in Ashraful's answer is correct:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="id">a1a</field>
    <field name="author">abcd</field>
    <field name="bibliography">a. b. ,c</field>
    <field name="body">This sample one.</field>
  </doc>

  <doc>
    <field name="id">a2a</field>
    <field name="author">xyz</field>
    <field name="bibliography">x. y. ,z</field>
    <field name="body">Sample Two.</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

Your post to `ExtractingRequestHandler` with `literal.id=VR` creates/updates a single document with `id` `VR`.

Just posting as `java   -jar post.jar VR.xml` will give you following results:

```
 "docs": [
  {
    "id": "a1a",
    "author": "abcd",
    "author_s": "abcd",
    "bibliography": "a. b. ,c",
    "body": "This sample one.",
    "_version_": 1558910648654495700
  },
  {
    "id": "a2a",
    "author": "xyz",
    "author_s": "xyz",
    "bibliography": "x. y. ,z",
    "body": "Sample Two.",
    "_version_": 1558910648656593000
  }
```